# Probability of a column between a range for a Normal Distribution

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I am trying to get a new column say `duration_probablity` which gets the probablity of a value falling between 6 and 12 hours . `P(6 < Origin_Duration ≤ 12)`

```
 dput(df)
structure(list(CRD_NUM = c(1000120005478330, 1000130009109199, 
1000140001635234, 1000140002374747, 1000140003618308, 1000140007236959, 
1000140015078086, 1000140026268650, 1000140027281272, 1000148000012215
), Origin_Duration = c("10:48:38", "07:41:34", "11:16:41", "09:19:35", 
"17:09:19", "08:59:05", "11:27:28", "12:17:41", "10:45:42", "12:19:05"
)), .Names = c("CRD_NUM", "Origin_Duration"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))

            CRD_NUM Origin_Duration
 1: 1000120005478330        10:48:38
 2: 1000130009109199        07:41:34
 3: 1000140001635234        11:16:41
 4: 1000140002374747        09:19:35
 5: 1000140003618308        17:09:19
 6: 1000140007236959        08:59:05
 7: 1000140015078086        11:27:28
 8: 1000140026268650        12:17:41
 9: 1000140027281272        10:45:42
10: 1000148000012215        12:19:05
```

I am not sure how to do that in R. I am trying to get cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution. The probability that a commuter’s stay-duration at certain station falling between 6 and 12 hours. 
The Output would be say for example 0.96 for duration 11:16:41

My CDF would be something like - `P(6 <X≤ 12) = Φ((12−μ)/σ)−Φ((6−μ)/σ)`

Comment: Did you try anything? What is the methodology behind calculating those probabilities? What is the expected output?

Comment: @Sotos I am not sure how to do that in R. I am trying to get  cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution. The probability that a commuter’s stay-duration at certain station falling between 6 and 12 hours. The Output would be say for example 0.96 for duration 11:16:41

Comment: So what is the CDF formulae? How is it defined? What do you expect the final result to be? You need to be explicit and provide as much information as possible

Comment: @Sotos `P(6 <X≤ 12) = Φ((12−μ)/σ)−Φ((6−μ)/σ) `

Comment: See `pnorm`, but something is missing in your formula: the link between the data and the parameters of your distribution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your question it is unclear whether you already know the mean and variance or not. I will discuss both cases. Also, I will assume you have reason to believe that the durations are in fact normally distributed.

**Known parameters:** If you have a pre-specified mean and variance given. Say, `mu = 11` and `sigma = 3`. Then you can use that `P(6 < X ≤ 12) = P(X ≤ 12) - P(X ≤ 6)`. The base R function `pnorm()` is able to calculate this:

```
mu    <- 11
sigma <- 3
pnorm(12, mu, sigma) - pnorm(6, mu, sigma)
# 0.5827683
```

**Unknown parameters, `P(6 < X < 12)`**: If you do not yet know what the mean and variance are, you can use estimations from your data and use the [student t-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) instead of the normal distribution (the story why this is called 'student' distribution, is nice too. You can find it in the wikipedia link). In order to find the mean and variance, it makes sense to first transform `df$Origin_Duration` from character to some time-type:

```
df$Origin_Duration <- as.POSIXct(df$Origin_Duration, format = "%H:%M:%S")

mu          <- mean(df$Origin_Duration)       # "2017-09-04 11:12:28 CEST"
df$demeaned <- df$Origin_Duration - mu
sigma       <- var(df$demeaned)^0.5           # 153.68
```

Note that I subtracted the mean first, before calculating the variation. I did this in order to have the duration in minutes. The standard deviation is therefore to be read as 153.68 minutes.

We will use the `pt` function to calculate the probability `P(X ≤ 12) - P(X ≤ 6)`. In order to so, we'd need a standardised / scaled / normalised version of `12` and `6`. That is, we have to subtract the mean and divide by the standard deviation:

```
x6  <- as.numeric(difftime("2017-09-04 06:00:00", mu), unit = "mins")/sigma
x12 <- as.numeric(difftime("2017-09-04 12:00:00", mu), unit = "mins")/sigma

deg_fr <- length(df$demeaned)-1

p_x_smaller_than12 <- pt( x12, df = deg_fr )    #  0.6178973
p_x_smaller_than6  <- pt( x6,  df = deg_fr )    #  0.03627651
p_x_smaller_than12 - p_x_smaller_than6
# [1] 0.5816208
```

**Added in response to comment: Unknown parameters, all entries:**

```
# scale gives the distance from the mean in terms of standard deviations:
df$scaled <- scale(df$Origin_Duration)

pt(df$scaled, df = deg_fr)
# [1,] 0.4400575
# [2,] 0.1015886
# [3,] 0.5106114
# [4,] 0.2406431
# [5,] 0.9773264
# [6,] 0.2039751
# [7,] 0.5377728
# [8,] 0.6593331
# [9,] 0.4327620
# [10,] 0.6625280
```

Comment: Mean and variance are unknown.   
For each Card number - based on the Duration, i need to find the probability.I got some information on how to start. My Question is for each line in the dataset, i need to get get Probability value

Comment: Excellent. Any reference to check normality of the distribution (Origin_Duration)